# iOS today extension causes Program ended with exit code: 0

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, today-extension, ios10-today-widget

I'm using Xcode 8.0, Swift 3.

I'm making today extension showing text and image, but frequently cause this message and today extension does not work.
rarely work.

> Program ended with exit code: 0

I saved data in realm, and today extension using the data(string, image)

is it cause a memory limit? so, how can i derease memory about today extension using??

My extension code:

```
class Information: Object {

    dynamic var Name = ""
    dynamic var Image : NSData?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "Name"
    }
}

class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

    var realm : Realm?
    var results : Results<Information>?
    var index = 0

    @IBOutlet var NameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func leftAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard index == 0 else {
            index -= 1
            loadData(index: index)
            return
        }
    }

    @IBAction func rightAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard index == (results?.count)! - 1 else {
            index += 1
            loadData(index: index)
            return
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setRealmFileURL()

        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *) {
            extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
        }else{
            preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 250)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        realm = try! Realm()
        results = try! Realm().objects(Information.self) 
        loadData(index: index)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    private func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
        // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

        // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
        // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
        // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData
        loadData(index: index)

        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
    }

    func loadData(index: Int){

        guard results?.count == 0 else {

            let objects = results?[index]
            NameLabel.text = objects?.Name
            ImageView.image = UIImage(data: (objects?.Image)! as Data, scale: 0.1)
            return

        }
    }

    @available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
    func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
        preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 250)
    }

    func setRealmFileURL(){

        var config = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: getKey() as Data)
        let directory = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.xxx")
        let realmPath = directory?.appendingPathComponent("xxx.realm")
        config.fileURL = realmPath

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mostly it is a problem with memory. The Widget will get cut off if it consumes to much.

Comment: how many memory the widget extensions could take? Less is better I know but on my iPad Pro last gen I currently use 25Mb and widget stop working immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Unless something in the app needs to change, don't use

```
completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
```

instead use

```
completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.noData)
```